# TypeScript imported constant is undefined

Tags: typescript

In my `Vue.ts` (Vue.js with TypeScript) I have defined a constant `serverUrl` in one file (http declaration) and I'm importing it into the other file with the class `AuthService`. But this constant is `UNDEFINED` in either property declaration or constructor of `AuthService`. In the `login()` function it's OK. What's the problem?
Here are my files. http:

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

export const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:63523';       // serverUrl Constant

export const http = axios.create({   timeout: 20000,   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'   } });
```

And the AuthService:

```
import { http, serverUrl } from '@/services/http';

export class AuthService {

  private authUrl: string = serverUrl + '/' + 'auth/login';    // serverUrl = UNDEFINED

  constructor() {
    this.authUrl = `${serverUrl}/auth/login`;                   // serverUrl = UNDEFINED
  }

  public login(login: string, password: string ) {
    const authUrl2: string = serverUrl + '/' + 'auth/login';   // serverUrl = OK!
    return http.post(authUrl2, {login, password});
  }
}

export const authService = new AuthService();
```

Comment: In theses two files do you have any circular dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, now I see I have.

Comment: @OndrejVencovsky can you please explain where are the circular dependencies (I am trying to reproduce your problem with basic TypeScript classes)

Comment: @OndrejVencovsky did you resolve your issue by removing the circular dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, removing the circular dependency has solved the problem. Thank you. Please add your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the variable `serverUrl` was not correctly injected in the file `AuthService` because there was a **circular dependency** between theses two files *(not visible from the code provided in the question)*.

The solution is to remove the circular dependency between theses two files and the variable `serverUrl` will be correctly imported.

Comment: Similar issue for me! Moved all the constants to a separate file and now we are all good :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a completely different problem. I had no circular imports/dependencies at all.

In my case, I was importing (in `MODULE A`) a barrel `index.ts` file (from `MODULE B`) with already ***precompiled*** code (in `dist` folder) and `package.json` pointing to it, which was hiding the real and fresh `index.ts`.

The solution was, of course, to the remove built `dist` folder where the TypeScript compiler was importing properly `index.ts` afterwards.

Here is the code:

## MODULE A

code:

```
import { TAG_PROPERTY_NAME, IFormActivity } from "@colabo-flow/i-core";

// `undefined` as we were importing old `dist/index.js` file without `TAG_PROPERTY_NAME` exported, instead of the new `index/ts` file with `TAG_PROPERTY_NAME` exported
console.warn(`TAG_PROPERTY_NAME: ${TAG_PROPERTY_NAME}`);
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@colabo-flow/i-core": [
                "<REST_OF_THE_PATH>/puzzles/flow/core",
            ],
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

## MODULE B

`package.json`:

```
{
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "module": "dist/index.js",
    // ...
}
```

`index.ts`:

```
export const TAG_PROPERTY_NAME = "tags";
// ...
```